# Redirect Specific Sub-domains .HTACCESS For WordPress Multisite With Wildcard SSL And No Internal Redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, multisite

I am attempting to map specific subdomains on my WordPress Multisite.

I have successfully mapped my multisite subdomains to their new domains.

**Example:**

### Store5.domain.com is now successfully changed to prodomain.com and everything works fine, up and to one point.

I need to make it so that anyone who knew about store5.domain.com will be redirected to prodomain.com

I have several instances of this, where I will need to replicate this code often as I perform these changes, so any assistance in understanding how I am using this code would be very helpful for me.

What can I do to safely adjust my .htaccess file so I can 301 redirect people from the specific domain(s)?

**Example:**
The now out of use: storeX.domain.com *301 permanent redirects* to the live prodomain.com

I cannot accomplish this in a simple fashion because I am using SiteGround, I am using a wildcard subdomain and wildcard SSL on the core domain to safely auto-secure the SSL certificates for any newly added subsites.

Because of the wildcard SSL, and because there is a Wildcard Subdomain, I am unable to create a core redirect for Store5.domain.com from within the control panel like normal, and because they are subdomains rather than sub-directories (sub.domain.com / not domain.com/sub) I cannot use a simple fix like a redirection plugin.

The only option I understand that will work will be redirection using .htaccess.

- **Additional Goal:** Ideally, I would like to include a way to make it so that if someone visits store5.domain.com/product/name will get redirected like a wildcard redirect, where it doesn't matter what they put after the slash, the first part will change from store5.domain.com to prodomain.com and the end of it will remain unchanged.*

My current htaccess looks like this (I have zero skill in writing htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Answer (score 0):

How I rewrote the core on .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store5\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule $ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Here is how my example now looks:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store5\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule $ https://domain1.com/$1 [L,R]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store2\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule $ https://domain2.com/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```